# Collapse menu not working with anchor links

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, menu

I've build a menu that collapse after you scroll down more than 250px from the top and returns to its original state when you go back to the top. But my website has some anchorlinks that link to the middle of the home page. When i go directly to these links the menu doesn't work. I have to scroll first. Is their a way to fix this?

This is the code i used:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('.fixed').data('size', 'big');
    });

    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 250) {
            if (jQuery('.fixed').data('size') == 'big') {
                jQuery('.fixed').data('size', 'small');
                jQuery('.fixed').stop().animate({
                    top: '-125px'
                }, 600);
                jQuery('.navbar-nav').stop().animate({
                    top: '15px'
                }, 600);
                jQuery('.dmbs-header-img').stop().animate({
                    opacity: '0'
                }, 200);
                jQuery('.logo-simple').stop().delay(200).animate({
                    top: '120px'
                }, 600);

            }
        } else {
            if (jQuery('.fixed').data('size') == 'small') {
                jQuery('.fixed').data('size', 'big');
                jQuery('.fixed').stop().animate({
                    top: '0px'
                }, 200);
                jQuery('.navbar-nav').stop().animate({
                    top: '0px'
                }, 200);
                jQuery('.dmbs-header-img').stop().animate({
                    opacity: '1'
                }, 100);
                jQuery('.logo-simple').stop().animate({
                    top: '-50px'
                }, 200);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle to help us find the solution more easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trigger the scroll event on anchor click (or on any other event you need).

```
jQuery('a').click(function(){
    jQuery(window).scroll();
});
```

**or**

Move your code inside a function and call it on scroll, or on anchor click:

```
function checkScroll(){
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 250)
    {
        // Your code
    }
    else
    {
        // Your code
    }
}

jQuery(window).scroll(function(){ 
    checkScroll();
});

jQuery('a').click(function(){
    checkScroll();
});
```

The second solution may give you more flexibility.

Comment: `jQuery(window).scroll(checkScroll);` will do.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan you're right, I just tried to reflect the syntax he used for readability